# How to sort dates in Angular 7 Material Data table?

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material, angular7

I created a datatable using ng generate @angular/material:table demoTable.

I have to sort by the date column. In the previous Angular versions I was able to use `sortingDataAccessor` for this purpose but for some reasons, I am not able to use that here.

Has anyone tried that using Angular 7 (more specifically after using the `ng generate` command to create the DataTable) ?

Comment: Did you look at this https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api ? Your question is not so clear to me. Are you able to sort? if so, the problem when sorting a date column?

Comment: @benshabatnoam I am not able to sort the date column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this steps and you should be able to sort your date column:

**HTML**:

1. Add *MatSortModule*

   ```
   import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';

   imports: [
     ...
     MatSortModule
     ...
   ```
2. Add *matSort* to your tabel

   ```
   <table matSort ...
   ```
3. Add *mat-sort-header* to your column th

   ```
   <th mat-sort-header="date"
   ```

Having this your column will emit the *matSortChange* event

4. Register *matSortChange* event

   ```
   <table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
   ```

**TS**:

5. Implement sortData() your way, something like this:

   ```
   sortData(event) {
     this.(your-list) = this.(your-list).sort((a, b) => {
       return a.date > b.date ? 1 : -1;
     }
   }
   ```

You can see this in greater details in [Angular Material Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview)

Also, created this [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-53651119) for you in case you get messed up with this

Answer (score 1):

You can do the sort usling MatSort like following:

```
import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
```

in your html:

```
 <mat-table #matSort="matSort" matSort>
```

in your ts component declare:

```
sortableList: MatSort;

@ViewChild('matSort') set yourDataSource(ms: MatSort) {

    this.sortStudentDetails = ms;
    yourDataSoruce = new MatTableDataSource(yourList);
    yourDataSoruce.sort = this.sortableList;
  }
```

this should work for all columns types.